# ¿Cómo migrar una cuenta previa de suscripciones de MercadoPago al nuevo personalizado?

Tags: mercadopago

Hemos creado cientos de suscripciones con el *checkout* básico, antes de que exista la opción del *checkout* personalizado para suscripciones.

Queremos ahora migrar al personalizado (`/v1`) y no sabemos cómo migrar nuestros datos actuales en *MercadoPago*. Todas nuestras suscripciones están almacenadas en `"preapprovals"` de *Mercadopago* y las nuevas entidades (*invoices* y **plan** al menos) no existen.

¿Existe alguna forma de migrar los datos, sin perder las suscripciones ni tener que volver a pedir datos de tarjeta de crédito a todos los usuarios?

¿O acaso la única solución es mantener en paralelo el nuevo y el viejo sistema mientras tengamos suscriptores en la versión anterior? Espero que no sea así...

No encuentro información al respecto en la documentación.

#### Datos de referencia:

1. Plataforma desarrollada en *Ruby on Rails*.
2. Toda la gestión con *Mercadopago*, a excepción de la página para poner los datos de la tarjeta, se gestionan mediante la versión anterior de la *API* de *MercadoPago*.
3. Queremos pasarnos a la nueva versión porque tiene funcionalidades que venimos esperando desde hace tiempo, como la posibilidad de saber la fecha de vencimiento de las tarjetas.

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente a Julio de 2017 la respuesta de MercadoPago por email es la siguiente:

> Actualmente no hay una forma de migrar a los clientes que tienen
>   suscripciones de V0 en forma automática a suscripciones de V1.

Esperemos que esto cambie en el futuro cercano... :(

Comment: ¿Te respondieron por mail o en algún foro público que se pueda enlazar?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro fue por email. Edité la respuesta para aclararlo y citar la respuesta exacta.